# FQL NoIndexFunctionException error 605 on an indexable column

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm attempting:

```
SELECT developer_id FROM app_role WHERE application_id='MY APP ID'
```

Using a  valid token, checked using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I receive this back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid application_id in WHERE clause", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

Now. the application_id is definitely correct. The auth token is checked and associated with that app id, and as far as I can see application_id is totally indexable.

Any ideas what the grief is here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need an app access token. Get it this way:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Then, use the same FQL request:

```
SELECT developer_id FROM app_role WHERE application_id='MY APP ID'
```

And there you go:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "developer_id": "1234567890"
    }, 
    {
      "developer_id": "9876543210"
    }
  ]
}
```